Clang Power Tools does not skip errors of a certain project in my VS Solution
I am trying to use Clang compiler to analyze our code base since it has very useful warnings. I am using Clang Power Tools within Visual Studio for this purpose.
In our solution there is a project that builds a plugin for a 3rd party software. The headers of this 3rd party software do not seem to agree with Clang and generate compiler errors. The problem is that, after these errors are generated the Clang compiler stops and does not go on with our files. We don't get any useful warnings.
"Continue on error" option is selected in the Power Tools settings and I know that it works because our code base also have some issues when compiled with Clang. Clang does not give up when it encounters errors and shows the warnings. Just not with that project. Are there any compile flags that can force the compiler to continue?
Thanks
